# Split test classes from the source classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm writing tests for plug-ins, now is my question is it better to make an apart test source folder for the test classes or can I put them all in the normal source directory?

Because I think it is better to split the functionality classes from the tests classes. So there can't be mistakes. Also if someones deploy the plug-in into the system, all the classes will deploy except the test classes. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Keep the test classes in a separate source folder.**

You are right.  It's best to have them in a separate source folder.  You do not want to deploy these classes when you deploy your plug-in, so it's best to keep them separate.  You also don't want these test classes in the same mix when you generate documentation.

Comment: So that is clear! :) But I don't think the only reason is that you don't want them in the source folder when you generate documentation..

Comment: No, the main reason is that these aren't library classes, they're test classes.  You don't want them mixed in with your library.